# Github controls in UFT directly to do checkin and checkout

Tags: hp-uft

i wanted to know how we can do version controlling directly from UFT with gitHUB,
how to get GitHub controls visible on UFT 14.1 version tool?

Thanks
Raju

Comment: Have you tried using Subversion under "Options" ? - That is what we use for SVN - I suppose should work the same

Comment: do i need to add the path of the .exe located? example my case gitHUB.exe

Comment: Yes, example of svn is - 

    "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseMerge.exe" /base:%base /theirs:%theirs /mine:%mine /merged:%merged

Comment: im adding github location as below, but not sure why im not able to see github controls, is something to be changed?"C:\Users\sophisqa\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\GitHubDesktop.exe"  /base:%base /theirs:%theirs /mine:%mine /merged:%merged

Comment: I havent used Github like i said, worked for me with SVN - however are you setting it up for the test you are using ex - GUI etc

Comment: Yes im setting up for GUI test

Comment: in that case buddy, the above command works for me.

Comment: seems to be we need to checkout project and then open in UFT is showing the controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied directly from UFT 14.01 help documents:

**Set up UFT to work with GIT**

- Before using GIT inside UFT you must configure GIT locally:
- Install the GIT or SVN client on the computer running UFT.
- Set up your GIT workspace on your computer. For details on see your GIT documentation.
- In UFT, create the test and save it in the folder configured to work with GIT or SVN.
- Add the document to your repository in GIT or SVN using the standard GIT and SVN commands.
- When prompted, enter your user credentials:
- GIT
  You are prompted for your user credentials the first time you push to the remote repository.

***Note:***
*If you need to clear your user credentials, select Tools > Clear All Credentials. Your user credentials for the SVN or GIT repository are removed and you will be prompted to enter them on the next update or commit.*

After you set up the workspace and add a document to the workspace, the relevant icons are displayed in your testing documents in the Solution Explorer and you can use GIT commands for your documents directly from the Solution Explorer.

---

Check [**this**](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/14.01/UFT_Help/Content/User_Guide/UFT_SVN_Integration.htm?Highlight=git) link for more detailed information.

Comment: I'm using UFT 12.02,I've tried all the above steps but no luck ,can you please help me.